# Running Linux DAEMON PHP files, does not execute exec, but does when ran from console

Tags: php, linux, bash, shell, command-line

I have a php script that works perfectly when ran form command line; including the exec().

The exec I do are calling some .sh scripts.

These .sh script are of type bash

So I call them:
exec('/bin/bash /home/user/soft/bin/mybash.sh > /dev/null');

It works great when I run my php from command line I see all the instructions; works also when use with an alias. but when I it via a daemon:

sudo -u myuser php -f /home/user/bin/serverwait.php eveything that should be done in the .sh are not being done. but the rest of the file is doing what it is suppose to do (it checks for open ports and write to a log file)

I tried looking at my php.ini for cli and all seems right.

Comment: do you get any errors ? also, have you tried using shell_exec() instead of exec() ?

Comment: Tried shell_exec also, but still same problem. I dont see any errors anywhere`.

Comment: Try changing the >/dev/null to a 2>&1 so you can catch (and please, print / log / whatever) the output AND errors your script is giving, this way you'll not be blind about them, and you'll fix the bug easily. Probably a $PATH problem ?

Comment: $output = exec('/bin/bash /home/user/mybash.sh 2 > &1'); Is that hte right way to do it? as $output does not give me anything?

Comment: Any risk on having the webserver running with a different user and therefore having a running permission issue?

Comment: Its not running under the web server config, but the CLI config. Unless you are telling me that running from deamon will use webserver config?

Comment: So all was actually running, but one of the script that was run by the php script did not have the correct rights on the file